# Cannot switch a connection string in LLBL Gen Pro

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, llblgenpro, llblgen

I have two databases with the same schema inside a Sql 2008 R2 Server, of which names are **Database1** and **Database2**. I connected and performed queries on the **Database1**, and then changed to  **Database2** to fetch my entities using the following code

```
this.ConnectionString = "Server=TestServer; Database=Database2;Trusted_Connection=true";
using (IDataAccessAdapter adapter = new DataAccessAdapter(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                var entities = new EntityCollection<T>();
                adapter.FetchEntityCollection(entities, null);
                return entities;
            }
```

(The connection string was set before executing the code).

I debugged the application and looked at the value of the connection string, it pointed to the Database2.

However, when I executed the above code, the result was return from the **Database1**. And if I looked at SQL Profiler, the statement was executed against **Database1**.

So, could anyone know what was going on? Why the query was executed against the **Database1**, not **Database2**.

PS: If I used the above connection string with plain ADO.NET, I was able to retrieve data from Database2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out what was going on. The reason was: by default LLBL Gen Pro uses fully qualified names like [database1].[dbo].[Customer] to access database objects, and the catalog is specified when generating entities. So you can't access objects just by changing the connection string.
Hence, to change to another database you have to **override** the default catalogue by using following code

```
 var adapter= new DataAccessAdapter(ConnectionString, false, 
                                 CatalogNameUsage.ForceName, DbName)
                             {CommandTimeOut = TenMinutesTimeOut};
```

More information can be found at the following [link](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/using%20the%20generated%20code/Adapter/gencode_dataaccessadapter_adapter.htm)